# Calculating CPU usage % for each process in bash

Tags: linux, bash, process

I am calculating each process' CPU usage %, and I do it with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function getTotalTime() {
    echo $(awk '{print $14+$15}' /proc/${1}/stat)
}

function getStartTime() {
    echo $(awk '{print $22}' /proc/${1}/stat)
}

function getActualCPUTime() {
    echo $(cat /proc/stat | awk '/cpu / {for(i=1;i<=7;++i) sum+=$i; print sum}')
}

pidArray=($(ls -l /proc | awk '$9 ~/^[0-9]+/ {print $9}'))
let index=0

for i in ${!pidArray[*]}
do
    if [ ! -z ${pidArray[$i]} ] && [ -e "/proc/${pidArray[$i]}/stat" ]
    then
        cpuP[$index]=$(getTotalTime ${pidArray[$i]})
        let index+=1
    fi
done

cpuT=$(getActualCPUTime)
sleep 1
#hz=$(getconf CLK_TCK)
cpuT=$((($(getActualCPUTime)-$cpuT)))
#uptime=$(cat /proc/uptime | awk '{print $1}')

let index=0
for i in ${!pidArray[*]}
do
    if [ ! -z ${pidArray[$i]} ] && [ -e "/proc/${pidArray[$i]}/stat" ]
    then        
        #aux=$(($(getTotalTime ${pidArray[$i]})-${cpuP[$index]}))
        #echo "$aux ->  $cpuT"
        cpuP[$index]=$((100*($(getTotalTime ${pidArray[$i]})-${cpuP[$index]})/$cpuT))


        echo ${cpuP[$index]}
        let index+=1 
    fi  
done
```

And for testing I start one or two times a `cat /dev/zero > /dev/null` to make some process use the CPU, but when I run my script and check the % I see ~150 if I'm running one of those process or two ~90% if running two.

I think it has something to do with the units of `/proc/stat` and `/proc/PID/stat`, but I can't figure that out.

Any clue?.

Thanks

Comment: when I do `cat /proc/zero` I see ksh using 13% CPU on my underpowered laptop ;-( . So > 75% CPU seems suspect.. Have you verified all of your math operations (I haven't ;-) ). Also you know about `top` and 100 other system monitoring tools? I assume you're doing this as a challenge, and not as a real tool. If you are, then consider reimplementing with many fewer subprocesses being started. I think most of the references to `/proc/${1}/stat` can be boiled down to one call to `awk`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter This is a challenge, the operations are correct (I have checked them in their respective files and calculated them with a calculator) the thing is that it says that process X has done 150 clock ticks and the other file says that the clock has ticked 100 times, but obviously there is something wrong there

Comment: a couple of ideas for you (and I'll warn you that I'm at the edge of my knowledge here ;-) . ... But first, clock ticks for %CPU? Those 2 ideas seem different (if still related). I can't do research about what is being displayed under `/proc/PID/stat` right now. The other thought is that the differences you see may be related to how the scheduler (not exactly the right term) is dividing up time. If you let it run longer you may see them even out. IHTH. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it, the problem was the order of reading values.

Before I read

`processes,cpu,sleep,cpu,processes`

and the right way is

`cpu,processes,sleep,cpu,processes`

Thats why the cpu value was too small and I was getting 150+% in some processes.